# Why are rotation matrices represented by the unit sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, kinematics

I have heard two statements:

1. "Although rotation matrices have 9D scalars, they only require 3D elements".
2. Rotation matrices are represented by the unit sphere.

Although I understand point 1), in the sense that the 3 unitary and 3 orthogonality constraints mean only 3 more scalars are needed to solve for the 9 scalars... what does the space of these 3 scalars look like geometrically?

Would it represent the unit sphere? Why or why not?

If not, how else can rotation matrices be thought of as the "unit sphere", especially considering rotation matrices are 9D matrices and not 3D points.

Comment: Which "unit sphere" do you refer to here (in terms of dimension) and where have you heard the two statements? Please provide more context.

Comment: See Section 3.6 here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/dynopt/readings/Rmetric.pdf

Comment: And other mentions of "rotation metrics as geodesics on the unit sphere"

Comment: I can't find the statements of your post in section 3.6 or any other place of that document.

Answer (score 1):

The spin group of [Wikipedia rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix?wprov=sfti1) paragraph explains well the link between  $\text{SO}(3)$ the group of 3D rotations or special orthogonal group and the sphere.